# What's the right way to parseFloat in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, precision

I notice some issues with the Java float precision

```
       Float.parseFloat("0.0065") - 0.001  // 0.0055000000134110451
       new Float("0.027") - 0.001          // 0.02600000000700354575
       Float.valueOf("0.074") - 0.001      // 0.07399999999999999999
```

I not only have a problem with `Float` but also with `Double`.

Can someone explain what is happening behind the scenes, and how can we get an accurate number? What would be the right way to handle this when dealing with these issues?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem is simply that `float` has finite precision; it cannot represent `0.0065` exactly. (The same is true of `double`, of course: it has greater precision, but still finite.)

A further problem, which makes the above problem more obvious, is that `0.001` is a `double` rather than a `float`, so your `float` is getting promoted to a `double` to perform the subtraction, and of course at that point the system has no way to recover the missing precision that a `double` *could* have represented to begin with. To address that, you would write:

```
float f = Float.parseFloat("0.0065") - 0.001f;
```

using `0.001f` instead of `0.001`.

Comment: by saying "float is getting promoted to a double" does it mean the compiler cast it to double internally ? does it promote float to double unconditionally whenever we use it with double for calculation ?

Comment: @user1389813: Yes. According to [§5.6.2 "Binary Numeric Promotion" of *The Java Language Specification* (Java SE 7 Edition)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2), there are various numeric operators, including `-`, with the property that both of their operands will be converted to the same type in order to perform the calculation. One of the conversion rules is, "If either operand is of type `double`, the other is converted to `double`."

Comment: Why does double have the highest priority ? is it because it's 64 bits ? because i see double -> float -> long -> int , and what about short ?

Comment: @user1389813: `double` has the highest priority because, with the exception of `long`, every other numeric type can be converted to `double` without losing information (though also, obviously, without recovering any information that's previously been lost). In the case of `long`, it's more complex, but in general you'll lose less information converting from `long` to `double` than vice versa -- especially since most possible values of `double` are well outside the range of `long`.

Answer (score 6):

See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). Your results look correct to me.

If you don't like how floating-point numbers work, try something like [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead.

Answer (score 5):

You're getting the right results.  There is no such `float` as 0.027 exactly, nor is there such a `double`.  You will *always* get these errors if you use `float` or `double`.

`float` and `double` are stored as *binary fractions*: something like 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/16...  You can't get all decimal values to be stored exactly as finite-precision binary fractions.  It's just not mathematically possible.

The only alternative is to use `BigDecimal`, which you can use to get exact decimal values.

Comment: so i am wondering how do we deal with something like Float.valueOf("0.074") // 0.07399999999999999999   and then times 1000 to that. Will i get back 74 ? or do i need to do a roundup every time ?

Comment: @user1389813, if you use BigDecimal you can alleviate a majority of those concerns.

Comment: You can't just multiply by 1000 and get the right answer.  (You _might_ get the right answer, depending on rounding behavior, or you might not.)  You _must_ use `BigDecimal` if you don't want these problems.

Comment: -1 - `new Float("0.027") - 0.001F` will return `.026`. The problem isn't the specific values they're using (`0.027`) but rather that they're mixing a float value (`new Float("0.027")`) with a double value (the literal `0.001`). See my answer, and @ruakh's answer, below.

Comment: Doubles will still have the same rounding problems eventually.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - Yes, but the values they're using only cause problems when they mix types. Output `new Float("0.027") - 0.001F` and you'll get `.026`. Output `new Double("0.027") - 0.001D` and you'll get `.026`. Output `new Float("0.027") - 0.001D` and you're for sure going to get the mess the OP is encountering. The problem isn't that they're using floats or doubles, but that they're using floats *and* doubles.

Comment: Do you really imagine that the only values the OP will ever care about are 0.027, 0.001, and 0.026?  Even if sticking to all floats or all doubles will help in this specific case, you're still pushing the OP down a road where the same problem will come up eventually.

Comment: That's true, but there are plenty of answers - both here and on other similar questions - which quickly come to the conclusion that floating point arithmetic is the heart of the problem and the OP should use `BigDecimal`. I prefer @ruakh's answer (and my own) because they are less generic and try to relate to the specific code snippet in the question.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Java Tutorials page on Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> A floating-point literal is of type float if it ends with the letter `F` or `f`; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally end with the letter `D` or `d`.

So I think your literals (`0.001`) are doubles and you're subtracting doubles from floats.

Try this instead:

```
System.out.println((0.0065F - 0.001D)); // 0.005500000134110451
System.out.println((0.0065F - 0.001F)); // 0.0055
```

... and you'll get:

```
0.005500000134110451
0.0055
```

So add `F` suffixes to your literals and you should get better results:

```
Float.parseFloat("0.0065") - 0.001F
new Float("0.027") - 0.001F
Float.valueOf("0.074") - 0.001F
```

Comment: i am wondering what happen to System.out.println((0.0065F - 0.001D)); ?

Comment: You get `0.005500000134110451`; try it. I edited it to make that clearer.

Comment: Yep I tried it, but why does it end up like that when D-F so as F-D ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean does it always have a long decimal floating whenever you mix type ? like double subtracts float or float subtracts double ?

Answer (score 3):

I would convert your float to a string and then use BigDecimal.

[This](http://rayfd.me/2007/04/26/the-evil-bigdecimal-constructor/) link explains it well

```
new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(yourDoubleValue));
```

Dont use the BigDecimal double constructor though as you will still get errors

Answer (score 1):

Long story short if you require arbitrary precision use BigDecimal not float or double. You will see all sorts of rounding issues of this nature using float.

As an aside be very careful not to use the float/double constructor of BigDecimal because it will have the same issue. Use the String constructor instead.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point cannot accurately represent decimal numbers. If you need an accurate representation of a number in Java, you should use the java.math.BigDecimal class:

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("0.0065");
```